# Where's the option "Scale In Lightmap" in unity 2017.3?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cant find this option in *Unity 2017.3*

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Lightmapping Window has been removed. Although, you can still access the  *"Scale In Lightmap"* option in Unity.

Select the GameObject. Go the *MeshRender* ----> *Lightning* then check the *Lightmap Static* checkbox. *Lightmap Settings* menu will appear under it and you can find *"Scale In Lightmap"* under it too.

If still confused, check the animated image below:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Everything mentioned above is still true in *Unity 2017.3*. There is only one more step to do. You **must** tick the `static` checkbox next to the name of the GameObject in order for the *MeshRenderer Lightmap* information to show in the MeshRenderer.

[image]

Comment: sorry ,i cant find "Lighting" in MeshRenderer Component.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/duoKN.png

Comment: I am using **Unity 2017.2** full version (**Unity 2017.2.0f3**). Is that the-same version you are using? If not, please update.

Comment: im using 2017.3.1

Comment: oh, i known, my version is Persional! not full version!

Comment: @Anderson I don't have 2017.3 on my side. Can you check in the Windows-->Lightning menu?

Comment: How about Global  and Object map tabs there?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzNlx.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1DRl.png

Comment: Check the update in my answer. It looks like you have to do one extra step in your version of Unity. My original answer is still valid though.

Comment: This is awful. I will have to download Unity 2017.3 to see what's going on. I can't do that now but when I do, I will edit my answer if you have not found a solution yet. Although, that will be hours from now.

Comment: i find the reason!. some plugin script result in this mistake. when i remove all script in my project. i find Lighting in MeshRenderer!!

Comment: Interesting. Which plugin?

Comment: @Anderson can you please tell us which plugin script caused this?

Comment: sorry, i remove all the plugins , so i cant know whats plugins lead to this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed TextMesh PRO, then you can delete the file called `"TMP_MeshRendererEditor.cs"` in your project. To restore all of them to their default state.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still not seeing the settings, make sure you've enabled Baked Global Illumination in the Lighting Setting tab (Window/Rendering/Lighting Settings). They only appeared for me after ticking it on and saving - easy to miss if you're using a different way to bake lightmaps than the built in baker.

(Unity 2019)